# Reference Javascript variable in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, reference, chart.js

I am trying to reference data from a user input in Javascript. The variable is passed in as JSON and I need to extract one value and reference this inside another JSON that creates a chart using Chart JS. The line labels is what I have tried but it does not seem to work. I am trying to avoid refactoring where possible. Any suggestions?

```
{
  "labels": "['jan', 'Feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']"
}

var lineChart = document.getElementById('line-chart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMacTool_DASHBOARD').value).labels,
    datasets: [{
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Processed",
        borderColor: "#9C2AA0",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Error",
        borderColor: "#123456",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Not Processed",
        borderColor: "#A8B400",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: '',
      fontColor: '#000000',
      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
      fontSize: 30
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#000000',
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        boxWidth: 20,
        fontSize: 20
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#000000'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#000000'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: There is no JSON in your example code. JSON is a text format, like CSV. All I see here are objects and arrays.

Comment: Updated the question to add JSON

Comment: That's not JSON either - it has single quotes, which don't parse as JSON. Can you give the errrors you're seeing from developer tools, if any?

Comment: The JSON is a string with single quotes inside it. There are no errors in Dev Tools. The chartjs chart does not display when I try to reference the labels dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. As others already commented, the data in your `input` element is not of valid `JSON` format
2. `labels` itself is a string since it is surrounded by double quotes

To make it work, you can perform the following steps.

1. parse the value from the input string with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and extract `labels` (that's what you already did).
2. [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all single quotes by double quotes in the obtained `labels` string.
3. parse the labels string to a `JSON` array using again [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
const labelsAsString =  JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMacTool_DASHBOARD').value).labels;
const labelsAsJSONString = labelsAsString.replace(/'/g,'"');
const labelsArray = JSON.parse(labelsAsJSONString);
```

Please have a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
const labelsAsString =  JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMacTool_DASHBOARD').value).labels;
const labelsAsJSONString = labelsAsString.replace(/'/g,'"');
const labelsArray = JSON.parse(labelsAsJSONString);

new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labelsArray,
    datasets: [{
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Processed",
        borderColor: "#9C2AA0",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Error",
        borderColor: "#123456",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
        label: "Not Processed",
        borderColor: "#A8B400",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: '',
      fontColor: '#000000',
      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
      fontSize: 30
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#000000',
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        boxWidth: 20,
        fontSize: 20
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#000000'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#000000'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMacTool_DASHBOARD" value="{ &quot;labels&quot;: &quot;['jan', 'Feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']&quot; }">
<canvas id="line-chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON I posted was valid but when parsed, returned a string. As uminder mentioned, labels needs to be an array hence replacing single quotes with double quotes and parsing twice returns an object. This worked! Really appreciate the help.